# 3D Model Translation deforming the object

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, 3d

I have created a program that renders a 3d cube, and now I'd like to change the position of the cube. The matrix multiplication I'm doing now seems to distort the cube instead of changing it's position. The distortion is small for values in the 0.1 - 0.4 range and fill the whole screen for larger values.

The vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexColor;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 cameraMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

out vec3 fragmentColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position =  projectionMatrix * cameraMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);
    fragmentColor = vertexColor;
}
```

Model.cpp (note that modelMatrix is initialized to an identity matrix and I'm using glm)

```
void Model::SetPos(glm::vec3 coords)
{
    modelMatrix[0][3] = coords[0];
    modelMatrix[1][3] = coords[1];
    modelMatrix[2][3] = coords[2];
}

void Model::Render()
{
    // Select the right program
    glUseProgram(program);

    // Set the model matrix in the shader
    GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(program, "modelMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(modelMatrix));

    // Setup the shader color attributes
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);

    // Setup the shader vertex attributes
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);

    // Draw the model
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, triangles);

    // Now disable the attributes
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
}
```

The other matrices are initialized like this and remain unchanged:

```
cameraMatrix = glm::lookAt(pos, target, orient);
projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(45.0f, 1280.0f / 720.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glm library produces column major matrices. You've also specified GL_FALSE to glUniformMatrix4fv which is correct for column major matrices. However, when you are setting the position you are setting wrong values. This code:

```
void Model::SetPos(glm::vec3 coords)
{
    modelMatrix[0][3] = coords[0];
    modelMatrix[1][3] = coords[1];
    modelMatrix[2][3] = coords[2];
}
```

Causes the matrix produce non 1.0 values in the w component after multiplication. This can cause some weird distortions. You should change SetPos to this:

```
void Model::SetPos(glm::vec3 coords)
{
    modelMatrix[3][0] = coords[0];
    modelMatrix[3][1] = coords[1];
    modelMatrix[3][2] = coords[2];
}
```